# How to check number exist or not in python for loop

Tags: python, csv, math

I have an excel sheet with this format:

```
from    amount  to

314 $470.21 275

12  $1,788.98   149

316 $2,949.53   417

5   $2,193.48   454

198 $1,402.76   371

82  $1,212.14   420

222 $1,167.72   396
```

and render all csv data with for loop:

```
import csv

def csv_data(path):
    with open(path) as csv_file:
        readCSV = csv.DictReader(csv_file)

        for line in readCSV:
            col_from = line['from']
            col_to = line['to']
            col_ammount = line['amount']
            print(col_from, col_amount, col_to)

csv_data('transactions.csv')
```

For example in "from column" i found value 314 now how can i check in all values of "to column" that this value is exist or not.actually i want to calculate current balance of all account numbers from and to.

How can add if condition properly in for loop ?

Comment: can you give an example How the current balance will be calculated.

Comment: Have you tried pandas package?

Comment: why don't you use something like sum([x['from'] for x in readCSV]) after all file is read?

Answer (score 0):

I give you are looking something like this..

```
for line in readCSV:
    if line['form']:
        #do something if "from" exist
    else:
        #do something if "from" do not exit
    if line['to']:
        # do something if "to" exist
    else:
        # do something if "to" do not exit
    if line['amount']:
        #do something if "amount" exist
    else:
        #do something if "amount" do not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your main problem is that you overwrite the `col_from`, `col_to` and `col_amount` list over and over again. Printing the value from within the loop may confuse you into thinking all your values would be stored in that lists. Try and call `print(col_from, col_amount, col_to)` outside the for-loop and you will only get the last element. A better way would be to create empty lists and `append` the items.

Secondly I think you should mind the data format which is int and float, but the `csv.DictReader` will return strings for all the elements in your matrix.

Then, checking if values of `col_from` also appear in `col_to` is easily done with list comprehension. You can create a list that contains "True" for all lines in which your condition applies and "False" if they do not (which is the case for all your sample data).

A suggestion that is close to your solution would be:

```
import csv

def csv_data(path):
    with open(path) as csv_file:
        readCSV = csv.DictReader(csv_file, delimiter=";", quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE) # supposed that your delimiter is ";", otherwise use , or \tab

        col_from, col_to, col_amount = [], [], [] # initialize empty lists

        for line in readCSV: # append entries to your lists
            col_from.append(int(line['from']))
            col_to.append(int(line['to']))
            col_amount.append(float(line['amount']))

        bool_list = [True if col_from[i] in col_to else False for i in range(len(col_from))] # A list with Trues and Falses
        return bool_list

print csv_data('transactions.csv')
# out: [False, False, False, False, False, False, False]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are successfully able to store values from the 'to' and 'from' columns in a list, you can perform an intersection operation on the 2 lists to get all the common values that exist in both the list.

```
col_from = [314, 12, 316, 5, 198, 82, 222]
col_to = [275, 149, 417, 454, 371, 420, 396]
intersection = list(set(col_from) & set(col_to))
```

Now `intersection`should contain all the common values from both the list, which in this case will be an empty list. You can also search for specific values by modifying it a bit

```
list(set([314]) & set(col_to))
```